# Assembly FASM getting parameters from command line

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, fasm

I am trying to execute a .exe from command line and pass to it a parameter which is the first argument after the .exe
I was able to print them in the console with the invoke to the WriteConsole function, but was not able to store it in a variable. How can I do this? Thank you

```
format PE GUI 4.0
entry start

include 'FlatAssembler\INCLUDE\win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

start:
Read parameters from command line
Display screen

       invoke GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
       mov ebx,eax
       invoke GetCommandLine
       mov esi,eax

   next:
       stdcall GetParameter,esi
       mov esi, edx ; skip first parameter (name of the file)
       stdcall GetParameter,esi
       jz  done_parameter 
       mov esi,edx
       invoke WriteConsole,ebx,eax,ecx,cnt,0
       invoke WriteConsole,ebx,crlf,2,cnt,0
```

Comment: Aren't you already getting a pointer to the string in EDX, as a return value from `GetParameter`?  You could store that pointer anywhere you want.  What are you trying to do that *didn't* work?  When you say "variable", do you static storage (like `dd 0`) with a label?

Comment: Yes, i do have a pointer to the string in EDX, how can I get that pointer to be the string?

Comment: In C terms, a string a 0-terminated (implicit-length) array of characters.  That array is variable length and can't fit in a register (you have to copy it around with loops, e.g. functions like strcpy).  So instead we just store a `char*` to that array, and sometimes also call that the string.  So either it makes no sense to say "get that pointer to be the string", or it already is.